Displaying MacBook screen content in visionOS app window after opening immersive space?
I was wondering if there are any possibilities similar to when connecting the Apple Vision Pro to e.g. a MacBook, one could somehow implement that the MacBook screen content would be displayed within the window of the app after opening the immersive space.
So far I haven't seen any APIs or something similar that might work for my case, and as I'm rather a novice in visionOS development I would appreciate any insider input and expertise.

This feature is not controlled by the app, but by the system. If you enable 'Immersive Experience Testing - Allow Mac Virtual Display' in the system settings app on Vision Pro, you can continue using Mac Virtual Display in Immersive apps.

Thanks! But what I was hoping for, would be a way to let the Mac Virtual Display appear within the window of my app (e.g. in the WindowGroup/ContentView). The current state is, that I have a separate app window and a separate window of the Mac Virtual Display, but I would like to merge them somehow so that I could use the Mac Virtual Display in the window of my app. If something like this is possible I would appreciate any help!

Not possible, if you're looking for screen capture of arbitrary Mac content. Would be a huge privacy/security hole if there were such an API. Now if you have your own app running on both the Mac and the AVP, you could use SharePlay and the Group Activities API to synchronize content and perhaps get to the experience you're hoping to provide.
